# Upload a json file in php

Tags: php, json, upload

I'm trying to upload a json file through PHP. This is the code that i have yet.

```
if( isset( $_POST['upload'] )) {
    $target = "/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']) ;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

I have Browse button and an Import button, and when i press Import, it doesn't say anything.

```
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='file' name='upload' value='Upload' id='upload' /></form>";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo "<form action='' method='post'><input class='button-secondary' type='submit' name='import' value='Import' id='import' /></form>";
    echo '</div>';
```

This is the code for the buttons.

Any idea how could I solve this issue?

Comment: Your import button belongs to a form that is not related to the file upload form - move your button code to within the first set of form tags

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are submitting the wrong form. There are two forms in your code, first with the input and the second with the button. So when you are pressing the button the second form is getting submitted and the `upload` is not available there. Try with -

```
echo "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo "<input type='file' name='upload' value='Upload' id='upload' />";
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo "<input class='button-secondary' type='submit' name='import' value='Import' id='import' />";
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: i changed it but it still doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable 'uploadedfile' is different from 'upload'...